# Test if the distribution of a discret sample came from a known distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Hello

I have a sample and I want to test if it is drawn from a discrete distribution (Binomal for example), I read that the KS test is more used, but as you know, the KS test can only be used for continious distribution.

I found a paper that solve this issue, the only problem is it's applicable only when the sample size is less then 30 ( and my sample size is greater than 30). Does anyone know how to perform the test? Thank you :)

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi+square+test+discrete+distribution for related questions and additional solutions.